# subscribe to two topics of int and sensormsg types

Tags: ros, subscribe, function, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to subscribe to topics that are of types int and sensor_msg .I want only one call back function to proces these two messages together .Please give an example code for this:

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248879/subscribe-to-two-topics-of-int-and-sensormsg-types/) by [anadgopi1994](https://answers.ros.org/users/28124/anadgopi1994/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2016-11-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If both messages have headers, then look into the [Time Synchronizers](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#Policy-Based_Synchronizer_.5BROS_1.1.2B-.5D) in the [message_filters](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters) package.

That would allow you to handle (time synchronised) pairs of incoming msgs in a single callback.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anadgopi1994](https://answers.ros.org/users/28124/anadgopi1994/) on 2016-11-27**:
I tried the code in time synchronizer which subscribe to two sensor_msg data types that is working.But when i tried to subcribe to two Int8 msg of type std_msgs A lot errors are showing.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-27**:
Well, both msgs need to have a header. `Int8` doesn't have a header, so that could explain the errors.

Any synchronisation strategy will need some piece of information with which it can determine which msgs 'belong together'. The `stamp` is one way of doing that. Without it, it won't work.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-27**:
Could you please mention that you've posted those 'errors' to [another question](http://answers.ros.org/question/248891) in the future? Thanks.